# how to create normal distribution by using matlab

Tags: matlab

for information..
i have some about machine maintenance schedule...for recondition and overhaul machine..
from the schedule there are information of when each machine happened to recond and overhaul.  has actual date and due date of machine for recond or overhaul in every year.
as example

```
    machine 1
```

actual date---2/1   (Recond)
due date------12/1

actual date---14/1 (Recond)
due date------24/1

actual date---24/1  (Overhaul)
due date------3/2

actual date---18/2  (recond)
due date------1/3

so..can you help me how to convert this data to normal distribution graph by using matlab..
because i want to compare each machine behavior..

thanks a lot..
i hope you can answer me as soon as possible

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. Exactly what do you mean by "normal distribution graph"? What value do you want graphed?

Comment: I dont understand your question at all yet.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you want to do, but here are some possible answers to your question:

- If you want to generate random data that follows a "normal distribution", use:

  ```
  data = mean_value + (randn(1,N) * standard_deviation)
  ```
- If you want to parse out data from the "logfile text" you mentioned, you could try:

  ```
  line = [d1,m1,d2,m2] = sscanf(line, 'actual date---%d/%d (Recond) due date------%d/%d');
  ```

  This will parse out the day/month values from the text.