# generate a random matrix consists of 100 rows and 100 columns that are normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 25

Tags: matlab, probability, matlab-guide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create normal distribution by using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970679/how-to-create-normal-distribution-by-using-matlab)

generate a random matrix consists of 100 rows and 100 columns that are normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation 25. 
I did the random matrix mat=rand(100,100) but then I dont know about normal distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation.

The next part is what is the probability of a given number in this matrix greeter than 25. 
As far as I understand, the number of probability should be the same everytime I run the script. Can I use randi?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get a helpful answer here, you're urged to show some research effort first. Here are some pointers: 1. Learn about [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), 2. Read MATLAB's documentation about [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html), 3. Define your question properly. What does "matrix greater than 25" mean? Do you mean an element in the matrix? You should also take look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970679/how-to-create-normal-distribution-by-using-matlab)...

Comment: @Shai yes. I've already flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: i dont think this one is similar to that question I know first part is similar but how about the probability part?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has two parts. So is my answer:

1. How to generate a matrix of size 100x100 where each entry is Normally distributed with mean = 0 and std = 25:

   You should use [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html):

   ```
   mat = randn(100,100) * 25;
   ```
2. What is the probability of an entry in `mat` to be greater than `25`:

   You can **sample** from this probability using your generated `mat` by:

   ```
   prob = mean( mat(:) > 25 );
   ```

   **However**, `prob` is **not** the probability of the event "entry in `mat` is greater than `25`". It is only a **sample** from that probability.

Comment: Can you explain why you multiply 25? I thought the standard deviation should be in the ()

Comment: the std is not an argument to `randn` that produces pseudo-random numbers with std = 1. In order to have different std, you simply multiply. Please see matlab's doc of `randn` - the link is in the question.

Comment: this is my code so far                                               mat = randn(100,100)*25
numbercounter = 0
for i = 1:size(mat,1)
    for j = 1:size(mat,2)
        if mat(i,j) > 25
            numbercounter = numbercounter + 1
        end
    end
end

Comment: but I want to get the probability ... when I run the script the numbercounter keeps changing ... I thought it should be the same number no matter how many times I run this script

Comment: The number of elements that are greater than 25 (`numberCounter`) is a **random variable** it is **NOT** a fixed number: for each random matrix `mat` `numCounter` indeed will have a different value. Please make sure you understand what you are asking... Are you sure you are entirely familiar with random variables, random matrices, etc.?

Comment: I dont understand at all and this is the first time I am using matlab .. the question is the question that I asked above .... my code now is mat = randn(100,100)*25

Comment: mat = randn(100,100)*25 this like is generating matrix 100*100 with random variables, am I correct? then I want to count so my next line is number counter = 10 then I use for loop

Comment: for i = 1:size(mat,1) for j = 1:size(mat,2) if mat(i,j)>25 number counter = number counter + 1 end end end

Comment: but the final answer that I need should be the probability not the numbercounter so the last line of my code is fprintf('%d/10000, P = %f\n', sum(randomnumbers>25), sum(randomnumbers>25)/10000) ... I have no clues the professor just said no matter how many times I run the script the probability should have the same value

Comment: +1: I applaud your patience!